# GitLab CI using msbuild succeeds but LASTEXITCODE is 1

Tags: msbuild, gitlab, continuous-integration

In Gitlab-ci.yml, following script is executed:

```
'MSBuild -restore -nologo -p:Configuration=Release -ignoreProjectExtensions:.vdproj,.isproj'
```

As a result, the msbuild is triggered. To build process fails with 52 errors. However, Gitlab is reporting that the build job is successful executed.

```
[E:\builds\Fjs5nhf5\0\benelux\solution\solution.BLL\solution.BLL.csproj]

    30 Warning(s)
    52 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:16.17
section_end:1632917270:step_script
[0Ksection_start:1632917270:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0K[0K[36;1mUploading artifacts for successful job[0;m
[0;mVersion:      13.10.0
Git revision: 54944146
Git branch:   13-10-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-03-21T09:13:31+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
[32;1mUploading artifacts...[0;m
Runtime platform                                  [0;m  arch[0;m=amd64 os[0;m=windows pid[0;m=4656 revision[0;m=54944146 version[0;m=13.10.0
[31;1mERROR: No files to upload                         [0;m 
section_end:1632917273:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0Ksection_start:1632917273:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up file based variables[0;m
[0;msection_end:1632917275:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[32;1mJob succeeded
[0;m
```

When running powershell and requesting to print "$?" after the MSBuild command, I get "True". Requesting to print $LastExitCode, I get "1"
I would expect "$?" to return "False" when then LastExitCode not equals 0.

We also notice that any script command triggered after the MSBuild script is no longer executed. Next stages in gitlab-ci.yml are executed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the stage as failed, you need to let Gitlab know about that condition by returning the correct code from the script.

If there is a PowerShell script associated with a given job, then the job will fail if the script returns an error code distinct from 0.
In order to do that, you should add the next line after any sensitive command in the script or at least at the end of it:

```
if(!$?) { Exit $LASTEXITCODE }
```

This will exit with the exit code from the previous command and, if any of these lines are distinct of 0, then the job will be marked as failed (and it will be marked as successful otherwise).

You can add as many lines like that one as you consider necessary.
Take into account that the $LASTEXITCODE variable is just that: the code returned by the last command run in the script, so you probably want to add several checkpoints in the script; depending on its complexity, of course

Comment: My gitlab-ci.yml contains follwing Lint code

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - exit 1
When running, the job doesn't fail!

$ exit 1
Cleaning up file based variables
Job succeeded

Comment: Hi Bart! 
Could you test it inside a build script? According to this official page, it should work: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html#job-marked-as-success-or-failed-incorrectly

Comment: I have found a solution. The issue is in the powershell shell. When using powershell-core, the problem does no longer appear. I do not understand yet why powershell-5 returns a false result.

Comment: Good to hear that you managed to resolve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. The issue is in the powershell shell. When using powershell-core, the problem does no longer appear. I do not understand yet why powershell-5 (Windows default) returns a false result.